# Dove posso trovare una folta lista di bisensi?

Tags: word-choice

Mi riferisco ai [bisensi](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bisenso/), per i quali, la lista più lunga che ho trovato è [questa](https://nairaquest.com/it/topics/5548-50-words-with-double-meanings-and-their-possible-meanings), che mi sembra scadente, se non altro, per il motivo che contiene solamente sostantivi, mentre manca totalmente di coppie come *sole*/*soli* (corpo/i celeste/i) e *sole*/*soli* (aggettivi plurali), o *stalle* (verbo all'imperativo) e *stalle* (sostantivo femminile plurale), o *impàri*/*ìmpari* (verbo vs aggettivo).

Comment: Ma chi l'ha scritta questa lista? E' stata scritta da qualcuno sbronzo? :-) Ad esempio: "Orecchino Un orecchino è una decorazione che si mette sulle orecchie, e che solitamente è fatta di oro, argento, legno, metallo... ed è anche una cosa che va fatta, cioè "in attesa" di essere fatta. " ?????

Comment: Confermo, quella lista ha seri problemi: dev'essere stata tradotta automaticamente da qualche altra lingua.

Comment: Anzi, sarebbe interessante capire da che lingua... In qualche lingua “in attesa” e simili si dice in modo uguale a “orecchino”?

Comment: Ma perché -1 solo perché l'ho nominata e linkata? :( Non è mica veleno...

Comment: "8. Tibia
La parola calda è usata per riferirsi ad una temperatura media (dell'acqua, per esempio), cioè calda; che non è né caldo né freddo. A sua volta, la tibia è anche un osso situato negli arti inferiori (gambe)." Penso sia spagnolo, 'tibia' in spagnolo vuol dire 'tibia' ma anche tiepida'.  Su 'orecchino' va indagato :-). @Enlico +1 per le risate.

Comment: Svelato il mistero di 'orecchino' e 'in attesa: 'pendiente'.

Comment: @BakerStreet, forse la #9 è proprio indicativa del fatto che la pagina non sia italiana.

Comment: @DaG: confermo quanto detto da BakerStreet: anche a me sembra una traduzione automatica dallo spagnolo.

Comment: Comunque sì, hai ragione, ho sentito una collega spagnola dire "ratòn" in riferimento al mouse, che è in linea con "topo".

Comment: Sì, @Enlico: sono convinta che si tratti di spagnolo tradotto alla lettera.

Comment: @ Enlico Sì la 9 è particolarmente parlante, ma è chiaro che non è italiano. Io non so niente di spagnolo, purtroppo, ma ho capito che era spagnolo da 'taco'. E Charo conferma.

Answer (score 3):

Un elenco niente male di bisensi ho trovato in:

https://www.pietroichino.it/?p=62036

Alcuni termini sono addirittura **tri-sensi**:

**Rombo:** 1) Figura geometrica; 2) Fragore; 3) Rombo nel senso del pesce.

**Granata:** 1) Rosso scuro; 2) Bomba; 3) Scopa.

---

Ne aggiungo alcuni invece farina del mio sacco.

Quello che mi piace di più perché abbastanza sorprendente:

**Alfiere** 1) Soldato che porta le insegne; 2) Pezzo degli scacchi.

La cosa particolare è che, a differenza di come si potrebbe pensare, sono parole diverse con etimologie diverse.

*Alfiere* nel senso del soldato viene dallo spagnolo  *alférez* , *cavaliere*.

Si potrebbe pensare, e io una volta lo pensavo, che l’alfiere degli scacchi venga dal soldato, in fondo gli scacchi sono un gioco di guerra. Invece no.

*Alfiere* negli scacchi viene da una parola araba, *al-fīl*, che significa *elefante*, e non c’entra niente con il soldato.

Questo mi ha anche illuminato sulla forma del pezzo degli scacchi, che ha una testa particolare, come un pallino in alto e una fessura sulla sommità: credo che la fessura sia la stilizzazione della bocca dell’elefante, e forse il pallino è il naso, comunque è una forma di provenienza animale, credo una stilizzazione della testa.

Qui le voci *Treccani* per una conferma del bisenso/doppia etimologia.

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/alfiere1/

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/alfiere2/

Altri due bisensi:

**Muta:** 1) Donna che non parla; 2) Tuta del subacqueo.

**Fico:** 1) Albero o frutto; 2) Persona che si fa ammirare, *cool* si direbbe in inglese.

È italiano:

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fico1/

E poi addirittura un **penta-senso**:

**Spera:** 1) Lett. e ant. sfera; 2) reg. Piccolo specchio, immagine riflessa; 3) Àncora galleggiante;  4) Lett. ant. Speranza; 5) Voce del verbo sperare.

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ricerca/spera/

**Citazione colta:**

*Non serba ombra di voli il nerofumo della spera* ,

incipit de *Gli orecchini* di Eugenio Montale, *spera* qui è usato nel senso di specchio.

Comment: Off topic: secondo me, alfiere degli scacchi potrà anche avere l'etimologia che Treccani dice, ma la forma del pezzo come è oggi deve sicuramente essersi originata dopo che lo stesso fraintendimento di cui tu sei stato vittima (e anche io) ha interessato un po' tutti. Non vedo come quella fessura non debba essere la visiera di un elmo. Opinione personale.

Comment: Può darsi, ma devo controllare, credo che gli scacchisti sappiano che non si tratta di un soldato, non credo che ci sia mai stato fraintendimento, e ho addirittura il ricordo di qualche immagine di pezzi antichi con figure di elefanti. Comunque mi hai fatto venire la curiosità e cercherò meglio.

Comment: Risposta molto interessante, grazie, +1. Rimarrei in attesa di bisensi (o multisensi) che coinvolgano funzioni grammaticali diverse, come gli esempi nella domanda.

Comment: Grazie sempre a te per gli spunti e le domande!

Comment: Per inciso, la motivazione per cui ho posto la domanda (a parte quella di far fare quattro risate con il link) è la volontà di creare/trovare un gioco di parole come [questo](http://www.jokeexplainer.com/2019/08/how-do-you-get-down-from-elephant.html).

Comment: Per accontentare @Enlico, alcuni bisensi verbo/nome o verbo/aggettivo sono già qui o nella pagina di Ichino citata: muta (che crea problemi a chi deve capire il famoso verso del Rigoletto), serba, amare, vendette, e aggiungerei porci, tende, fallo, sei, sale e innumerevoli altri. Ci vorrebbe un dizionario solo per questo. Un'utile fonte può essere un repertorio di crittografie mnemoniche, che si basano sui bisensi per il loro funzionamento, come per es. due di quelli linkati qui: http://www.enignet.it/pubblicazioni-bei/elenchi-repertori-e-antologie.html